# Increase poly smoothness

Tags: vertices

What is the best way to increase smoothness on this model?
Specially on that highlighted part which is too noticeable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a mirror modifier?

Comment: No, I'm not. I duplicated part and mirrored.

Comment: Did you remove doubles after mirroring ? To smoothen adjacent vertices you could use *Smooth* operator from `W` menu or **Smooth** modificator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you duplicated your mesh and mirrored it, you have two halves that are still unconnected.

The Subsurf modifier stops at the places where when you have unconnected vertices:

[image]

To fix this, enter edit mode, select all of your vertices (kbd>A,), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and select **remove doubles**

[image]

[image]